# find and return the sum of all nodes present in a generic tree in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I want to find sum of all nodes in tree (not binary) recursively, I have tried it but i am not getting right answer. Generally i struggle understanding how recursion work in a question and i am not able to understand it's working in. Please help

```
int sum(TreeNode<int>* root){

      int s = 0;
      for(int i=0; i<root->child.size(); i++){
            s += root->data;
            sum(root->child[i]);
      }
      return s;

}
```

Please take a look at the tree structure: [Tree Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9XF1.jpg)

Comment: Does this have to be recursive?  A level-order traversal using a `std::queue` and a `for` loop would be less intensive on the program stack.

Comment: `int sum(TreeNode<int>* root)` This function returns the sum. `sum(root->child[i]);` this call **does not** use the return value., You compute it and then just throw it away. OTOH `s += root->data;` this is executed in a loop. If your node has N children, you sum node's own data N times. If it has no children, its data doesn't contribute to the sum at all.

Comment: How can i store child data in every call and not just throw it away ?

Comment: @Jessica Doing this recursively seems awkward, IMO.  A simple [level order traversal](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a117b0574f93344) is tidier and won't blow out the program stack if there are many nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a generic tree with `n` children, you can think of the recurrence relation as:

```
sum(tree) = value(root) + sum(child[0]) + sum(child[1]) + ... + sum(child[n-1])
```

Then, the recursive solution is simply:

```
int sum(TreeNode<int>* root)
{
    // value(root)
    int s = root->data;

    // no. children
    int n = root->child.size();

    // + sum(child[0]) + sum(child[1]) + ... + sum(child[n-1])
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        s += sum(root->child[i]);
    }

    return s;
}
```